# remotely debug user browser without installation on local PC

Tags: remote-debugging

Hello Stack Overflow Community,
This is my first post, so if I misstep, please help me correct.

I am a support manager and we are dealing with a browser issue that we cannot replicate. It appears to happen for our end user in no visible pattern. The same user will have success one day from the same network and PC and failure the next day or even next hour.

What we are looking for is a method to remotely debug an end user's PC without additional installation that will involve their IT. We have tried using Internet Explorer developer tools, but those are proving to create additional problems while running.

Thank you for your gift of shared knowledge.

Comment: I'm not sure what level of 'debugging' you mean. If it's just that you want to 'watch' the user to identify what they're doing that is causing the problem, then there are lots of screensharing applications around, many of which require no installation.

Comment: Hi Dave, we are trying to capture information deeper that we can see with a screen share. We are already using Cisco WebEx to screen share and from there we were having the user turn on Internet Explorer developer tools. The problem is that the IE dev tools cause issues themselves and we cannot seem to save the Console or Debugging tab from IE tools. Ideally if we could have the user install something like Fiddler, that would be best. But getting an end user in the the hospital setting to install software is tenuous at best given their restrictions on access and time.